# How do I look up the HTML5 'data' attribute when parsing an xml file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, html

This is the code I have. I am trying to pull out the "data" attribute and drop it into the div at the end with id "question". I'm pretty new to JS and know there must be something really basic that I'm doing wrong, what is it?!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
 <head>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 function display() {

  var base = document.getElementById("output");
  var CompleteSuggestion = base.getElementsByTagName("CompleteSuggestion")[1];
  var suggest = CompleteSuggestion.getElementsByTagName("suggest")[0];
  var question = suggest.getAttribute("data")[0].firstChild.data;



  document.getAttribute("data").innerHTML = question;


 }


  </script>

 </head>
 <body onload="display()">

 <xml id="output" style="display: none;">

        <CompleteSuggestion>
        <suggest data="hello">
      </CompleteSuggestion> 


 </xml>

<div class="question" id="question"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: With the provided xml I believe `CompleteSuggestion` is `null` since you use index `[1]`. You mean index `[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a better way to get the attributes from an xml file

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

//use ajax to grab the xml file
//I had an xml file named your.xml in the same directory as this script
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "your.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {

        //when the file has loaded via the ajax request loop over each suggestion element
        $(xml).find('suggestion').each(function() {

            //get the value of the first attribute (data), from this suggestion row
            console.log( this.attributes[0].value );
        });
    }
});
</script>
```